# Ignore DNS servers from DHCP lease

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, dhcp

I've an Ubuntu box. When I connect to a wifi network, I get the IP address for `wlan` interface using `dhclient`. The problem is, I don't to use the DNS servers provided by the DHCP lease. How can I do that? I tried entering static dns servers for my `eht0` and reloading its configuration, but the DHCP provided DNSes win anyway.

Comment: Why don't you use NetworkManager ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/ you can put one of these lines in /etc/dhclient.conf or /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf :

```
supersede domain-name-servers 202.54.1.2, 199.2.3.4;
```

OR

```
prepend domain-name-servers 1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5;
```

-replacing the IPs with your desired DNS servers. (Duh...) :)

Comment: You can also see the most relevant options via `man dhclient.conf` in a terminal.  For this answer, search (/) for *supersede*.